# Unable to parse the JSON When same name exist multiple times

Tags: c#, json

I am parsing the JSON to extract the name details.But, I am getting an error.
Could you please help me to extract the name details.

```
var jsonResult = JObject.Parse(jsonFileContents);
Console.WriteLine("Name :" + jsonResult["Name"]);
```

jsonFileContents:

```
[
  {
    "Name": "Joe",
    "Age": 25,
    "Rank": 1
  },
  {
    "Name": "Peter",
    "Age": 32,
    "Rank": 2
  }
]
```

Error:
            Unhandled Exception: Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Error reading JObject from JsonReader. Current JsonReader item

Comment: That's an array of objects.  Might help if you use an index to get the first object.  The array doesn't have a property `name`.

Comment: If you are getting an error, you need to include the error in your question

Comment: updated the error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks, your input JSON is JSON Array. It needs to be parsed as below

You need to specify the Index to extract the respective elements. for example, To extract the first name.

```
var jsonResult = JArray.Parse(jsonFileContents);
Console.WriteLine("Name :" + jsonResult[0]["Name"]);
```

If you want to extract all the name details, then you can iterate and get it as below

**Extract all the name Details from JSON Array:**

```
       var jsonResult = JArray.Parse(jsonFileContents);
       for(int i = 0; i < jsonResult.Count; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(jsonResult[i]["Name"]);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to look at the structure of the json object

It’s jsonobject >index array of objects > each object contains the name age

So getting first object will be like jsonresult[0][“Name”]

Comment: Getting the same error.But,After changing the JObject as JArray, then jsonResult[0]["Name"] is giving the result.